# OptaPlanner domain modelling - multiple PlanningEntity classes?

Tags: java, optaplanner, domain-model

I am trying to construct the domain model for an optimization use-case, using OptaPlanner. In my mind the following problem should be modeled using two `@PlanningEntity` classes, but since the OptaPlanner documentation often argues that you usually only need one `@PlanningEntity` class, I am wondering if I am modelling my problem incorrectly, or whether this is in fact a situation to have two `@PlanningEntity` classes.

Consider a school timetabling problem like the example provided by OptaPlanner [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/school-timetabling), but imagine we are also planning and optimising which students attend a lesson. If these problems are independent, then this could be solved by writing two different solvers, and running the "student planner" solver first, and then the "schedule planner" solver. However, assume that these two are not independent. For example, constraints regarding the placement of students in certain lessons might interact with when these lessons take place (student X prefers lessons in the morning, student Y prefers lessons in the afternoon, and student Z cannot have two lessons directly in a row). So, when optimising, I would like the solver to be able to consider both the timeslot of lessons as well as the students attending a lesson.

My idea to model this would be to extend the `TimeTable` class in the example with a second `@PlanningEntity` modelling student to lesson assignments, and in the `Lesson` class the `studentGroup` field would be replaced with a list containing all the students assigned to that lesson, probably in the form of a shadow variable (though this is an implementation detail).

1. Am I correct in that in the above example, two different `@PlanningEntity` classes ("Student to lesson assignment" as well as `Lesson`) are appropriate? Or is there a way to model this problem using only a single `@PlanningEntity`? I know that a `@PlanningVariable` cannot be a list, so I assume a `List<Student> students` planning variable is not possible.
2. Am I correct that a `@PlanningEntityCollection` can only be a field on the `@PlanningSolution`? Or is there a way to have the student assignments be a field on the `Lesson`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to assign lessons to time and rooms and students to lessons, I think you truly need two `@PlanningEntity` classes. As multiple students can attend multiple lessons, you can perhaps create a new `StudentAssignment` `@PlanningEntity` class with `Lesson` as its `@PlanningVariable`.

Yes, the `@PlanningEntityCollection` can only be a field on the `@PlanningSolution` class. What can be put inside the `@PlanningEntity` class is the `@ValueRangeProvider` that provides values for the `@PlanningVariable` field.